# Android bubbles in UI like Beats Music app

Tags: android

I would like to implement UI pattern which were used in [Beats Music app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beatsmusic.android.client)  for selection of music genres.

The main idea here is that some physics engine should be used to make it possible to swipe through bubbles top-bottom-left-right.

In general this pattern looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: HI, have you found any solution??

Comment: i would like u to have a look at this , it will surely help you,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47322572/7603313