# How to create UI and Controls like Apple Music App in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, apple-music

[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLelPMQmUzA&t=100s)

I want to create view and animation like **Apple Music App** available in iOS. But, I want to do it in Android similar to above video link.

> **Is it possible to create such views in Android? How can I achieve this? How to proceed in this?**

Please share any links and references.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32156561/1576416) question is already asked but has no answer.

> *I want to implement something like Apple's new Music app which is synced with iTunes. Bubbles on the move, according to mood we can select a music, genre etc.
>   I want this type of gesture with moving bubbles in Android. Can anyone help me out, how to figure out and play with Gestures or Motion Controls of that bubbles anywhere in screen. Also is there any support library if available would be very helpful to implement and move further. The bubbles are to be created randomly by a web service call.*

Any suggestion in this will be helpful.

Comment: have you considered using box2d library? I watched the video and it seems like a physic simulation

Comment: @lelloman can u share links and references for box2d?

Comment: sure, [here it is](http://www.jbox2d.org/) if you search box2d on youtube you can make an idea

Comment: Hi, do you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

i have used box2d with libGdx to configure the gradle in android studio...
u can refer my project on github which has selectable bubbles in random motion, and u can ask if any doubts...
https://github.com/mohitKejriwal/Bubble-UI-Android