# Bubble picker Android Library

Tags: android, scroll

Bubble picker Android Library: https://geekonjava.wordpress.com/2017/05/09/bubble-picker-android-library-tell-me-how/
 I'm trying to scroll screen right and left, because my bubbles are big and are not wrapping to the screen. I have tried to use HorizontalScrollview and different other tricks, but no success. Help me, please

Comment: Try this https://github.com/igalata/Bubble-Picker

Comment: It's the same library, the problem is that I can't swipe screen left/right to see the all bubbles. I mean I wasn't able to place bubbles inside HorizontalScrollview

Comment: show your code.

Comment: if u want u can use my project, might help u
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47322572/7603313

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomBubblePickerView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val bubbleSpeed = 100f
    private val updateInterval = 16L // Update every 16 milliseconds (approximately 60 FPS)

    private val handler = Handler()
    private val updateRunnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            updateBubblePositions()
            invalidate()
            handler.postDelayed(this, updateInterval)
        }
    }

    private fun updateBubblePositions() {
        val timeInSeconds = updateInterval / 1000f

        for (bubble in bubbles) {
            bubble.centerX += bubbleSpeed * timeInSeconds
            if (bubble.centerX > width + bubble.radius) {
                bubble.centerX = -bubble.radius
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        handler.post(updateRunnable)
    }

    fun removeAllBubbles() {
        bubbles.clear()
        invalidate()
    }


    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable)
    }

    private val bubbleSize = 80f
    private val gridSize = bubbleSize * 2

    data class Bubble(
        val id: String,
        var centerX: Float,
        var centerY: Float,
        val radius: Float,
        val color: Int,
        val text: String,
    )

    private val bubbles = mutableListOf<Bubble>()
    private var onClickCallback: ((Bubble) -> Unit)? = null

    init {
        setOnClickListener {
            handleClick(it.x, it.y)
        }
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        val desiredWidth = suggestedMinimumWidth + paddingLeft + paddingRight
        val desiredHeight = suggestedMinimumHeight + paddingTop + paddingBottom
        setMeasuredDimension(
            resolveSize(desiredWidth, widthMeasureSpec),
            resolveSize(desiredHeight, heightMeasureSpec)
        )
    }

    fun addBubble(
        id: String,
        color: Int,
        text: String,
    ) {
        val maxAttempts = 100
        var attempts = 0
        var newCenterX: Float
        var newCenterY: Float

        val maxGridX = (width / gridSize).toInt()
        val maxGridY = (height / gridSize).toInt()

        do {
            newCenterX = (Math.random() * maxGridX * gridSize).toFloat()
            newCenterY = (Math.random() * maxGridY * gridSize).toFloat()
            attempts++
        } while (hasCollision(newCenterX, newCenterY) && attempts < maxAttempts)

        if (attempts < maxAttempts) {
            val newBubble = Bubble(id, newCenterX, newCenterY, bubbleSize, color, text)
            bubbles.add(newBubble)
            invalidate()
        } else {
            Log.d("CustomBubblePickerView", "Bubble placement failed after $attempts attempts.")
        }
    }

    fun removeBubble(id: String) {
        val bubbleToRemove = bubbles.find { it.id == id }
        if (bubbleToRemove != null) {
            bubbles.remove(bubbleToRemove)
            invalidate()
        }
    }

    fun setOnBubbleClickListener(listener: (Bubble) -> Unit) {
        onClickCallback = listener
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        val paint = Paint()

        for (bubble in bubbles) {
            val bubbleCenterX = bubble.centerX
            var bubbleCenterY = bubble.centerY

            if (bubbleCenterY - bubble.radius < 0) {
                bubbleCenterY = bubble.radius
            } else if (bubbleCenterY + bubble.radius > height) {
                bubbleCenterY = height - bubble.radius
            }
            val image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.bubble_2)
            val imageWidth = image.width.toFloat()
            val imageHeight = image.height.toFloat()
            val imageLeft = bubbleCenterX - imageWidth / 2
            val imageTop = bubbleCenterY - imageHeight / 2
            canvas.drawBitmap(image, imageLeft, imageTop, paint)
            paint.color = Color.WHITE
            paint.textSize = bubble.radius / 2.5f
            val textWidth = paint.measureText(bubble.text)
            val textX = bubbleCenterX - textWidth / 2
            val textY = bubbleCenterY + paint.textSize / 2

            canvas.drawText(bubble.text, textX, textY, paint)
        }
    }


    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                handleClick(event.x, event.y)
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    private fun handleClick(x: Float, y: Float) {
        val clickedBubble = findClickedBubble(x, y)
        clickedBubble?.let {
            onClickCallback?.invoke(it)
        }
    }

    private fun findClickedBubble(x: Float, y: Float): Bubble? {
        for (bubble in bubbles) {
            val distance = sqrt((x - bubble.centerX).pow(2) + (y - bubble.centerY).pow(2))
            if (distance <= bubble.radius) {
                return bubble
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun hasCollision(centerX: Float, centerY: Float): Boolean {
        for (bubble in bubbles) {
            val distance =
                sqrt((centerX - bubble.centerX).pow(2) + (centerY - bubble.centerY).pow(2))
            if (distance < bubble.radius + bubbleSize) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).